# Simple past or past perfect with by

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the following

1. By the 18th century, the Portuguese in India lost their commercial influence.
2. By the 18th century, the Portuguese in India had lost their commercial influence.

Thank you.

Comment: **By** the time the 18th century began, the process of the Portuguese losing their influence had finished. This is different from saying that a certain event happened **in** the 18th century.

Comment: That means 1) is wrong?

Comment: 1. does not seem natural to me (unless you changed 'by' to 'in', which would slightly change the meaning).

Comment: Why does not @KateBunting post her excellent comment as an answer?